# English and other translation within single paper

Tags: publications, translations

I want to to translate my math preprint to Russian. Actually, the preprint is already translated, but I'm in doubt should I include the Russian version together with the English, earlier version of the preprint (available at kolosovpetro.github.io/series_representation_of_power_function). If it's acceptable to combine two language versions of math articles, can you provide some examples?

Is it acceptable to write a paper in English and add a a Russian translation at the end of the English version?

Comment: What field? What sort of paper? Why would you want to? Please say more.

Comment: I wanna to translate my math. preprint to russian, actually, preprint is already translated, but i'm in doubt should I include the russian version togather with english one, earlier version of preprint is available at https://kolosovpetro.github.io/series_representation_of_power_function/ . If it's acceptable to combine other versions of math articles, can you provide sime examples? thank you

Comment: It would be best to add the information to the question itself Comments can get removed and this should be preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think it is probably a mistake to do this. While it is possibly convenient and makes the paper more widely available, it will cause some problems for reviewers. Most of the available reviewers will speak one language or the other only and will either have to trust that the translation is adequate or find some other means. At best this will slow you down. Math especially may be a difficult field in which to do this as machine translation is likely not as good as for (some) other things.

The big issue is, do the two halves, really say the same thing. That can be a bit subtle. It isn't impossible to deal with it, but it would be a strike against the paper in the minds of editors, I think.

Probably not a good idea. Publish in the language you are most familiar with and provide a translation separately.

Carefully mark the translation *as* a translation and reference the *original* version within it.

Comment: perhaps, would I leave a link to translated version within actual paper ?

Comment: That would be better, and I doubt it could be objected to. See my recent edit's last line, also.

Comment: I agree that the paper should be submitted for publication (and then published) in just one language, but I see no problem with putting a two-language version on the arxiv.